# How to reduce coupling between Presentation & Business layers (JPA, Netbeans)?

Tags: java, design-patterns, jpa, controller

I am working on Java database project, and i'am doing my best to separate my DAL/BL layer to the presentation layer (web/desktop app).

Somewhere, behind a "Search" button, i must invoke a method that returns a list of "OpArticle" objects. In a standard way, one should inject the following code:

```
OpArticleJpaController articleCpontroller = new OpArticleJpaController(_emf);
listArticle = articleCpontroller.findOpArticleEntities();
```

where "_emf" is an EntityManagerFactory instance supposed to be instanciated in the application start-up.

I am asking about a more efficient (cleaner) design pattern that let me not obliged to pass a reference of the "EntityManagerFactory (_emf)" to the controller classes, in the Presentation Layer.

I am thinking about the following approach:

```
listArticle = DaoFactory.getArticleController().findOpArticleEntities();
```

where "DaoFactory" manages the creation of controllers' objects as follows:

```
c1 = DaoFactory.getArticleController();
c2 = DaoFactory.getCustomerController();
etc...
```

Does it violate any best practice knowing that i must update the Factory by adding a new instanciation' method each time a new controller or any service provider class is developed and added to the DAL/BL layer.

Best regards.

Comment: Actually instantiate the EntityManager Factory is very expensive process, it should be instantiated once on the entire application life, and yes seeing what you are doing it seems that EMFactory should be reference only in DAO layer, controller and services should not know about its existence.

Comment: Yes. Surely the EntityManagerFactory (emf) will be created once in the entire application life. I am asking about the ability to avoid passing a reference of the (emf) in the presentation layer (PL) classes. Because this increases the coupling of the (PL) and the DAL/BL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do that way although you need to modify the factory each time you add a controller you can modify it in a compatible way that doesn't break any important OO principle.

But you will benefit a lot if you use a Dependency Injection Framework like [GUICE](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) and you simply leave EMF as a dependency.